# In Pandas, how to .diff() rows when one or more rows are non numerical

Tags: python, pandas, diff

I have an example pandas notebook which obviously worked in the past (not locally for me).

[simple stock tracking program](https://github.com/koaning/calm-notebooks/tree/master/stocks)

The second line of the two lines of code shown here creates an error.

```
df_stocks = pd.read_csv("bigmac.csv").iloc[500:1800]

df_returns = df_stocks.set_index('date').diff()
```

The csv file does contain columns that are non numerical. The error is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

I tried deleting the non numerical columns from the csv file and the error goes away, as expected. That is, if differencing non numerical columns was the issue, which it may not be.

Of course, something in my pandas distribution may have been depreciated, of which, I am not aware. I don't know what version the original code was written in but my version is 1.2.4 .

I may have gone down the "rabbit hole" because it was my understanding that ".diff()" would not attempt to difference columns with non numerical data.

How to proceed?

Thank You

Comment: the example notebook doesn't show any non numerical columns except for the date (for which you run set_index) - iirc `df.diff` never worked if there were any non-numeric (and non bool) columns

Comment: Asish M. I think that you are correct. Don't know how this example ran in the first place. thank You